# Launch an .exe file from Win32

Tags: winapi, createprocess

I have been trying to start an `exe` file from a Win32 application, however I have been unable to get it to work. I want to pass an argument to it as well, but I don't think I am doing it correctly. A similar question has been asked here before, but it seems like they wanted to run a command (`cmd.exe`), not start another exe file. Specifically, I want to launch the Java appletviewer.

My current code is this:

```cpp
LPCWSTR pszViewerPath = L"C:\\Path\\to\\appletviewer.exe"; // I know that this path is correct
PWSTR pszFilePath;
// get the path to the HTML file to pass to appletviewer.exe, store it in pszFilePath...

STARTUPINFO si;
PROCESS_INFORMATION pi;

ZeroMemory(&si, sizeof(si));
si.cb = sizeof(si);
ZeroMemory(&pi, sizeof(pi));

CreateProcess(pszViewerPath,
   pszFilePath,
   NULL,
   NULL,
   FALSE,
   0,
   NULL,
   NULL,
   &si,
   &pi);

CloseHandle(pi.hProcess);
CloseHandle(pi.hThread);
```

The problem I am having is that a command prompt window briefly appears before disappearing without a trace.

What am I doing wrong? I was originally going to use `ShellExcecute` but read that that was inefficient.

How do I fix this? Thank you for your help.

Comment: You don't check for errors. Start by fixing that. Documentation tells you how.

Comment: "*a command prompt window briefly appears*" - that is perfectly normal behavior when you run a console app... "*before disappearing without a trace*" - ... because the app didn't wait ask for any user input.

Comment: If you use `LPCWSTR`, you should initialize it as `LPCWSTR pszViewerPath = L"C:\\Path\\to\\appletviewer.exe";`. And make sure to call the `CreateProcessW` function. And you use `pszFilePath` It seems to be wrong, the parameter indicates that the command line to be executed, and you did not initialize it. Reference:[CreateProcessW function](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/api/processthreadsapi/nf-processthreadsapi-createprocessw)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When using both the `lpApplicationName` and `lpCommandLine` parameters of `CreateProcess()`, it is customary to repeat the application file path as the 1st command-line parameter.  This is even stated in the [`CreateProcess()` documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/api/processthreadsapi/nf-processthreadsapi-createprocessw):

> If both `lpApplicationName` and `lpCommandLine` are non-NULL, the null-terminated string pointed to by `lpApplicationName` specifies the module to execute, and the null-terminated string pointed to by `lpCommandLine` specifies the command line. The new process can use `GetCommandLine` to retrieve the entire command line. **Console processes written in C can use the `argc` and `argv` arguments to parse the command line. Because `argv[0]` is the module name, C programmers generally repeat the module name as the first token in the command line.**

Try something more like this:

```cpp
LPCWSTR pszViewerPath = L"C:\\Path\\to\\appletviewer.exe"; // I know that this path is correct

PWSTR pszFilePath;
// get the path to the HTML file to pass to appletviewer.exe, store it in pszFilePath...

PWSTR pszCmdLine = (PWSTR) malloc((lstrlen(pszViewerPath) + lstrlen(pszFilePath) + 6) * sizeof(WCHAR));
if (!pszCmdLine)
{
    // error handling...
}
else
{
    wsprintf(pszCmdLine, L"\"%s\" \"%s\"", pszViewerPath, pszFilePath);

    STARTUPINFO si;
    PROCESS_INFORMATION pi;

    ZeroMemory(&si, sizeof(si));
    si.cb = sizeof(si);
    ZeroMemory(&pi, sizeof(pi));

    if (!CreateProcess(
        pszViewerPath,
        pszCmdLine,
        NULL,
        NULL,
        FALSE,
        0,
        NULL,
        NULL,
        &si,
        &pi))
    {
        // error handling...
    }
    else
    {
        // optional: wait for the process to terminate...
        WaitForSingleObject(pi.hProcess, INFINITE);

        CloseHandle(pi.hProcess);
        CloseHandle(pi.hThread);
    }

    free(pszCmdLine);
}
```

In which case, there is no point in using the `lpApplicationName` parameter at all:

> If lpApplicationName is NULL, the first white space–delimited token of the command line specifies the module name.  If you are using a long file name that contains a space, use quoted strings to indicate where the file name ends and the arguments begin

```cpp
CreateProcess(NULL, pszCmdLine, ...)
```

Comment: Thank you! This will actually be extremely helpful for other applications, too. By the way, the missing `L` was a mistake I made writing the question.